# I'm DRYing my specs, but have a issue with making dynamic requests for controller tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I was noticing that I kept repeating the same spec for actions prohibited to certain users. Especially when the action is not allowed, the redirect and flash should always be the same (more or less), so I tried writing a `shared_example` like this:

```
  shared_examples_for "no access" do |action|
    it "redirects the user to the homepage" do
      get action
      subject.should redirect_to('/')
    end

    it "sets a flash message" do
      get action
      expect(controller).to set_flash[:alert]
    end
  end
```

But then quickly realised that get doesn't accept the action variable as a variable.

Any idea on fixing this, or achieving something like this some other way?

Comment: Why do you say it "doesn't accept the action variable as a variable"? Are you getting an error and if so, what is the error specifically? How are you using the shared examples in your specs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify your shared example as follows...

```
shared_examples "no access" do
  it "redirects the user to the homepage" do
    action
    expect(response).to redirect_to('/')
  end
end
```

Then in your tests you pass `action` as a let block...

```
it_behaves_like "no access" do
  let(:action) {get :show, id: my_record.id}
end
```